Integral of a rectified power law with Gaussian noise for non-integer powers
I am interested in the following integral:
$$f(x)=\int dt \phi(t) [x+\sigma t]_+^n $$
where $\phi(x)=e^{-x^2/2}/\sqrt{2\pi}$ is a standard Gaussian distribution, $[x]_+=max(x,0)$ is a rectification, $n\ge0$ an exponent, and $\sigma>0$ the magnitude of the noise.
Denoting $\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x \phi(t)dt$, through integrating-by-parts I could calculate it manually for all integer $n$ values:
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
   x\Phi(x/\sigma)+\sigma \phi(x/\sigma), & \text{n=1}\\
            xf_1(x)+\sigma^2 \Phi(x/\sigma), & \text{n=2}\\
            xf_{n-1}(x)+\sigma^2(n-1)f_{n-2}(x), & \text{n>2}
   \end{cases}$$
Is there a way to extend this to non-integer values of $n\ge0$?

Change variables $u=x+\sigma t$ then your integral is of the form $\int\limits_0^\infty du \ u^ne^{-(u-\sigma t)^2/2}$ which a CAS evaluates to a pair of hypergeometric $_1F_1$ functions: see the last point in 'special cases' on the wiki page

Thanks for pointing this out, @Sal! My CAS does not have any of those, so the wiki link is most helpful. BTW, you mean $(2\pi\sigma^{2})^{-1/2}\int_{0}^{\infty}due^{-\left(u-\mu\right)^{2}/2\sigma^{2}}u^{n}$.

Also, the difference in the limits (integrating only from 0 to inf) is different from the $_1F_1$ result.

No problem! And yes my mistake I forgot how to change variables :) In case it's useful the result of Mathematica is $f(x)=(2\pi\sigma)^{-1/2}\int\limits_0^\infty du \ e^{-(x-u)^2/2\sigma^2}=\frac{\left(\sigma \sqrt{2} \sigma \right)^n}{\sqrt{8 \pi  \sigma }}\left[n x \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}\right) , _1F_1\left(\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma ^2}\right)+\sqrt{2} \sigma  \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) , _1F_1\left(-\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2};-\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma ^2}\right)\right]$

Dear @Sal, the prefactor seems wrong (in numerics), was it mistyped? I think it should be $(\sqrt{2}\sigma)^n/\sqrt{8\pi\sigma^2}$

Also, write it as an answer and claim your bounty!

As requested :) There should be no more typos in the answer- I checked it numerically this time

Given
$$\tag{1}
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt \ e^{-t^2/2}[x+\sigma t]^n_+
$$
with the change of variables $u=x+\sigma t$, so that $[x+\sigma t]_+=[u]_+$, hence the integration region is over $u>0$ and we have
$$\tag{2}
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_0^\infty du \ e^{-(u-x)^2/2\sigma^2}u^n
$$
Using a CAS, (2) evaluates to a pair of confluent hypergeometric functions (of course we need $n\gt-1$ to avoid a non-integrable pole at zero)
$$\tag{3}
f(x)=\frac{2^{n/2}\sigma^{n-1}}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\left[ \sigma  \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) \, _1F_1\left(-\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2};-\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma ^2}\right)+\sqrt{2} x \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right) \, _1F_1\left(\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma ^2}\right)\right]
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function, and $_1F_1$ is the Kummer confluent hypergeometric function.
